# Mudar de página "OnClick" sempre "invalid views to insert"

Tags: angular, ionic

Gostaria que ao clicar em um botão, mudasse de página.
Estou em `inicio` e gostaria de ir para `add-oferta`.

> inicio.html

```
<ion-fab bottom right >
    <button ion-fab color="secondary" (click)="addOferta()"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-fab>
```

> inicio.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { ServiceProvider } from '../../providers/service/service'
import { pageAddOferta } from '../add-oferta/add-oferta'

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'PaginaInicial',
  templateUrl: 'inicio.html'
})
export class PaginaInicial {

    produtos: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public servidor: ServiceProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PaginaInicial');
  }

  getProdutos(ev: any) {
    const val = ev.target.value;
    if(val!=''){
        this.servidor.getProdutos(val)
        .subscribe(
            data => this.produtos = data,
            err => alert(err)
        );
    }
  }

  addOferta(){
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(pageAddOferta);
  }

}
```

Mas ao acionar a função desejada sempre aparece o erro abaixo:

```
Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert
```

Não sei onde está o erro ou o que estou fazendo de errado.
Vi que a função é chamada corretamente, mas nunca chamada a página que preciso.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se a página pageAddOferta tem o "@IonicPage()" nela. Se tiver vc está chamando a função "setRoot()" errado.

Essa seria a forma correta de chamar a próxima página:

```
  addOferta(){
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('pageAddOferta');
  }
```

Por que isso acontece? Sua página é LazyLoad (contém o @IonicPage() nela), ou seja, ela não está declarada no app.module, então quando vc está chamando ela assim "this.navCtrl.setRoot(pageAddOferta)", o angular não reconhece ela pois não está declarada.

Quando ela é LazyLoading, vc tem que chamar ela passando o nome da página (string) "this.navCtrl.setRoot('pageAddOferta');"

Caso vc queira remover o LazyLoading da sua página, remova o "@IonicPage()" dela, apague o arquivo "suapagina.module.ts" e declare ela no "app.module.ts".